# Downloading SWF from HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I want to download an SWF file from this page: http://www.surgerysquad.com/surgeries/virtual-laser-tattoo-removal

But when I search the HTML source, it has a javascript something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
(function(){
try {
// Registering Dynamically Published SWFs
swfobject.embedSWF("/cont/wrapper/wrapper.swf","so_targ_wrapper_690907206","667","517","10.0.0","",{
surg_id : "09"
},{
"wmode" : "transparent"
},{
"id" : "fm_wrapper_690907206",
"name" : "fm_wrapper_690907206",
"styleclass" : "flashmovie"
});
} catch(e) {}
})();
</script>
```

You are able to download SWF file using this like but it doesn't play the SWF: http://www.surgerysquad.com/cont/wrapper/wrapper.swf

I guess the problem is not adding `so_targ_wrapper_690907206` like it had in the code.
Please tell me how do I download the full version of SWF using that js.

Comment: The second parameter in the **.embedSFW(...)** method is the id/name of the **HTML** element on that page (if you search the page source you will find it) which is to hold the new **HTML** tags this method creates for the **Flash** application to appear on the page. Simply put, it has nothing to do with the fact the downloaded **SWF** does not play.

Answer (score 0):

You're downloading the embeded SWF file fine - as [Organis mentioned in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75546850/downloading-swf-from-html-page#comment133314733_75546850), the ID of the container, or the one passed in the `embedSWF` argument has nothing to with it. If I download and play `wrapper.swf` in my local Flash Player, it plays fine up until the point it needs to load additional content.

If you have a Flash disassembler like the [JPEXS Flash Decompiler](https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler), you can traverse the ActionScript and see that it loads at least one additional SWF file: `vis/slides.swf` - however it seems to be determining the full URL path from an XML-populated array, and I can't see the path to the file with a casual look. But that would be the way to figure it out.